# getElementById() changing to class

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

i have a script that would hide and show triggered by onclick="javascript:showDiv() and onclick="javascript:hideDiv()
but wish to change it to class otherwise be able to enter multiple id's
any suggestion?

```
function hideDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById('divA').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function showDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById('divA').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

Comment: like with `.className`?  You could also do `.className += " xyz";` (Note the space between '"' and 'x'.

Comment: Would you mind using Jquery?

Comment: Why the `if (document.getElementById) {`? Is there a browser that doesn't support getElementById?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[document.querySelectorAll<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)** and then change the id of divA to `class="divA"`

```
function hideDiv() {
 if (document.querySelectorAll) {
    var set = document.querySelectorAll('.divA');
    for(var i = 0; i < set.length; i++){
     set[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
 }
}

function showDiv() {
 if (document.querySelectorAll) {
    var set = document.querySelectorAll('.divA');
    for(var i = 0; i < set.length; i++){
     set[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery and do this:

```
$('.myclass').toggle();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function hideDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById('divA')) {
        document.getElementById('divA').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function showDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById('divA')) {
        document.getElementById('divA').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

`getElementById()` expects a parameter.